# Installing phpMyAdmin error

Tags: centos

```
su -
yum install phpMyadmin
```

gets me:

```
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
 You could try using --skip broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is on Centos 5, a basic LAMP server. Here is the packages I have installed for php and mysql.

```
mysql55-libs-5.5***
php53-mysql-5.3***
libmysqlclient15-5.0***
mysql55-5.5.***
mysql55-server-5.5***

php-53-devel-5.3***
php-53-bcmath-5.3***
php-53-snmp-5.3***
php-53-mysql-5.3***
php-53-common-5.3***
php-53-5.3.3-1***
php-53-gd-5.3***
php-53-pdo-5.3***
php-53-soap-5.3***
php-53-xmlrpc-5.3***
php-53-cli-5.3***
php-53-mbstring-5.3***
php-53-xml-5.3***
```

Sorry for the *** in the packages, I had to hand type them out because the Linux PuTTy won't let me copy and paste, let me know if I need to be more specific with the packages.

When I go to http://myip.com/phpmyadmin, nothing shows up; when I do rpm -qa | grep phpMyAdmin, nothing shows up.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin can simply be downloaded from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php and unpacked into a web reachable directory. You don't have to use a package manager.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of this now. All is well other than it says "The mysqli extension is missing." - I don't have php-mysql extension installed and apparently that has mysqli in it. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, you helped me with this question perfectly, I'm just going to start a new question. Thanks again to you and Andy Smith.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the `phpmyadmin` package depends on `php-common`. You've got `php-53-common` installed, which conflicts with `php-common`, so as a result `phpmyadmin` won't install.

The easiest thing to do in your case would be to install phpMyAdmin manually. Grab it from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php), unpack the archive into `/var/www/html` and rename the directory to `phpmyadmin`. Follow the instructions in `config.sample.inc.php` and you'll have the latest version of phpMyAdmin running.